# Why call void on an unknown argument before returning another function call?

Tags: javascript, arity, ramda.js

What's the significance of calling `void` before returning in [ramda's arity function](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/152180f4d92d68b5298389794bcd81ed364eedc0/ramda.js#L537-L552)?

Comment: Perhaps it actually removes the last argument? I do notice that it takes a parameter `n` that would not be desired to pass to the closure when passing `arguments`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ramda co-author here. That is an artifact of some of the code linting we do. We want to be warned if there are ununsed parameters in a function definition. In the case of `arity`, the params are only there to create a function with the correct, well, arity. Adding the `void arg_n` passes the linter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I assumed it would be for something like linting after someone mentioned warnings in a comment (which was then deleted).

Answer (score 1):

To just make sure no weird errors/warnings are popping up, as far as I know. If by any change the variable is made elsewhere with values. void makes it empty.

Comment: Void doesn't alter the value of a variable, it just "[evaluates the given _expression_ and then returns `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)".  For example `(function (a) { void a; return a; })(123);` returns `123`, not `undefined`.